# Where can I learn the basics of writing a lexer?

Tags: language-agnostic, lexer, compiler-construction

I want to learn how to write a lexer. My university course had an assignment where we had to write a parser (and a lexer to go along with it) but this was given to us with no instruction or feedback (beyond the mark) so I didn't really learn much from it.

After searching for this topic, I can only find fairly advanced write ups which focus on areas which I feel are a few steps ahead of where I am at. I want a discussion on the basics of writing a lexer for a very simple language which I can use as a basis for investigating tokenising more complex languages.

At this stage I'm not really interested in best practices or optimisation techniques but instead prefer a focus on the essentials. What are some good resources to get me started?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Basically there are two main approaches to writing a lexer:

1. Creating a hand-written one in which case I recommend [this small tutorial](http://stlab.cc/legacy/how-to-write-a-simple-lexical-analyzer-or-parser.html).
2. Using some lexer generator tools such as [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29). In this case, I recommend reading the tutorials to the particular tool of choice.

Also I would like to recommend the [Kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) from the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) documentation. It runs through the implementation of a simple language and in particular demonstrates how to write a small lexer. There is a C++ and an Objective Caml version of the tutorial.

The classical textbook on the subject is [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) also known as the Dragon Book. However this probably falls under the category of "fairly advanced write ups".

Comment: The Kaleidoscope tutorial was the part that really answered this question for me.

Comment: For more info on writing an LL(1) parser by hand see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769).

Answer (score 13):

The [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is probably the definitive guide on the subject, although it can be a bit overwhelming. [Language Implementation Patterns](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) and [Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) are great resources as well.

Comment: +1 on the Dragon book. Learned A LOT from it when in university. Yeah, there's a lot there, but if you're really interested in compiler design and implementation, it's a great resource.