# How to turn opening/closing tags into an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, recursion, xml-parsing, preg-match

I have a Natural Language Processing parse-tree as

```
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
```

[image]

and I want to store it in an associative array, but there is no function in PHP, as NLP is usually done in python.

Thus, I should parse the opening and closing parenthesis to build a tree-structured associative array. I can think of two options

1. Replacing the parenthesis with arbitrary XML or HTML tags, and parse it as an XML or an HTML document.
2. Using regex.

I think the first approach is non-standard, and the regex pattern can break in complex cases.

Can you suggest a reliable approach to do so?

The associative array can have any form, as it is not difficult to manipulate it (I need it in a loop), but it can be something like

```
Array (
[0] = > word => ROOT, tag => S, children => Array (
    [0] word => I, tag = > NP, children => Array()
    [1] word => ROOT, tag => VP, children => Array (
        [0] => word => ROOT, tag => VP, children => Array ( .... )
        [1] => word => ROOT, tag => PP, children => Array ( .... )
)
)
)
```

or it can be

```
Array (
[0] = > Array([0] => S, [1] => Array (
    [0] Array([0] => NP, [1] => 'I') // child array is replaced by a string
    [1] Array([0] => VP, [1] => Array (
        [0] => Array([0] => VP, [1] => Array ( .... )
        [1] => Array([0] => PP, [1] => Array ( .... )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of the expected result? You should consider a universally accepted serialization method such as JSON if you need different languages to use eachother's data.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry, I should have provided it. I added an example. I get it from Standford CoreNLP, which is written in Java. Although it gives formatted the results in XML and JSON, the parse section is provided exactly as above, probably because parenthesis is the standard tag in linguistic studies.

Comment: @Emma no that's a wrapper for python to get the parse results from CoreNLP. It returns the string given above. If I find a python function, I can replicate it as a PHP function, but even in python people are interested in drawing the parse (like the above image) rather than arranging in an array.

Comment: Please don't yatta-yatta your expected result.   As is, we only have one situation where a `word` is not assigned `ROOT` assumedly because it has no children.  By posting the remaining portions of your desired output array, this requirement becomes crystal clear. Is your input data always formatted/spaced as you have posted? Can the newlines be relied upon?  Lastly, how big are your pajamas and how did you get the elephant inside them?

Comment: @mickmackusa your assumption is correct. We can even mix tag and word, as words always appear as a single child of a tag (as illustrated). Yes, the format can be relied upon, as it is a standard form followed by CoreNLP. The line breaks can be relied upon, but I doubt if they can be of any use, as they do not follow the levels. It's the modern marketing for one-size-fits-all :)

Comment: @mickmackusa I added a simplified expected output array following your comment.

Comment: No, you are still using `( .... )`. With an attempt to self-solve included, I can upvote.  Otherwise, this is a "requirements dump" -- which some people deem downvote-worthy. I will not consider answering until a coding attempt is provided. This is inline with my posting philosophy which intends to protect this community from being abused as a free coding service.

Comment: @mickmackusa I clipped the children for readability and simplicity. I will expand the array to full.

Comment: Please post some of your tries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lexical analyzer generator likes [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison) or [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) or just write your own lexer by hands, This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216449/where-can-i-learn-the-basics-of-writing-a-lexer) has some useful information you need.

Here is a quick and dirty POC snippets written in PHP that will output an associative array as expected.

```
$data =<<<EOL
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
EOL;

$lexer = new Lexer($data);
$array = buildTree($lexer, 0);
print_r($array);

function buildTree($lexer, $level)
{
    $subtrees = [];
    $markers = [];
    while (($token = $lexer->nextToken()) !== false) {
        if ($token == '(') {
            $subtrees[] = buildTree($lexer, $level);
        } elseif ($token == ')') {
            return buildNode($markers, $subtrees);
        } else {
            $markers[] = $token;
        }
    }

    return buildNode($markers, $subtrees);
}

function buildNode($markers, $subtrees)
{
    if (count($markers) && count($subtrees)) {
        return [$markers[0], $subtrees];
    } elseif (count($subtrees)) {
        return $subtrees;
    } else {
        return $markers;
    }
}

class Lexer
{
    private $data;

    private $matches;

    private $index = -1;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        preg_match_all('/[\w]+|\(|\)/', $data, $matches);
        $this->matches = $matches[0];
    }

    public function nextToken()
    {
        $index = ++$this->index;
        if (isset($this->matches[$index]) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->matches[$index];
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => S
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => NP
                            [1] => I
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => VP
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => VP
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => V
                                                            [1] => shot
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => NP
                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => Det
                                                                            [1] => an
                                                                        )

                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => N
                                                                            [1] => elephant
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => PP
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => P
                                                            [1] => in
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => NP
                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => Det
                                                                            [1] => my
                                                                        )

                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => N
                                                                            [1] => pajamas
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```